# Azure spring boot deployment - container problem

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, maven-plugin, azure-deployment

I have a problem with my spring boot deployment on azure. I followed the steps on 
[microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin?view=azure-java-stable) and i was able to start my webservice locally. 
I also deployed the example of microsoft and used my mysql database which is also hosted on azure and had no problems.

I also set the application setting WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT on maximum.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>billSharingWebservice</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>

    <plugin>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <deploymentType>jar</deploymentType>

      <!-- Web App information -->
       <resourceGroup>billSharing</resourceGroup>
                <appName>billsharing</appName>
                <region>westeurope</region>  

           <!-- Java Runtime Stack for Web App on Linux-->
           <linuxRuntime>jre8</linuxRuntime>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After deployment on azure i got the following logs:

```
2018-10-25 16:09:22.956 INFO  - Starting container for site
2018-10-25 16:09:22.958 INFO  - docker run -d -p 43892:8443 --name billsharing_0 -e PORT=8443 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=billsharing -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=96d743e51352785f93233abee2c7fb3857cba42475b37377d206d1fee114218f -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/java:8-jre8_0000000000  
2018-10-25 16:10:26.869 ERROR - Container billsharing_0 for site billsharing has exited, failing site start
```

Which isn't really helpfully.

Maybe someone has an idea to help me
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used your `pom.xml` and set **WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT** to `1800`, the **log stream** didn't show "`Container XXX for XXX initialized successfully`" and the site showed unavailable service.

Then I tried the `pom.xml` Microsoft recommending and it worked fine.So maybe you could try my settings. Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- servlet dependency. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- tomcat support.-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
             <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>1.4.0</version>
             <configuration>
               <deploymentType>jar</deploymentType>

               <!-- configure app to run on port 80, required by App Service -->
                <appSettings>
                 <property> 
                   <name>JAVA_OPTS</name> 
                   <value>-Dserver.port=80</value> 
                 </property> 
                </appSettings>

               <!-- Web App information -->
               <resourceGroup>myStorageGroup</resourceGroup>
               <appName>mvntest03</appName>
               <region>eastus</region>  

               <!-- Java Runtime Stack for Web App on Linux-->
               <linuxRuntime>jre8</linuxRuntime>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And here is my **log stream** [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfeVv.png).

If you also have other settings or still have questions ,please let me know.

Comment: @Lenni2309 if my answer could help you, could you accept my answer. Thanks.